# Maven test run locally but fail in Azure Pipeline using Azure DevOpz Maven POM.xml All test giving time Elapsed error

Tags: java, azure, selenium, maven, azure-pipelines

Here is my POM.xml
When I run from TestNG or Maven test from locally all the test cases are working fine but in pipeline it gives me this error time elapsed .please check the below image attached
Using
Chrome Driver
TestNG
Maven
Azure Devopz Pipline

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Selenium_Framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>Selenium_Framework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   
</properties>
<build>
<plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Have a relook, it's an _`AssertionError`_. Should be an easy fix.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium thank you but problem is it same assertion passing test cases in local but failed in pipeline just in first 6 second .

Answer (score 0):

> Maven test run locally but fail in Azure Pipeline using Azure DevOpz Maven POM.xml All test giving time Elapsed error

You could try to update your selenium dependencies to the most recent release.

And according to the warning message "unable to find cDP implementation matching 103", you could try to `selenium-devtools-v103` in the dependencies, like:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v103</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If above not resolve your issue, please share the debug build log as txt in your question.

Comment: Leo Liu-MSFT not working above sol please help me more thanks

Comment: @usamasohail, What is the result if you try to use it?

Comment: Same result ...all test cases bare failing on just login test case just given me error assertion